# Create a hollow UIImage overlay above parent UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, overlay

I have below code to create a UIImage layer on top of another UIImage layer
The top layer acts as a highlighter of some objects on the primary layer

```
CIImage *overlay1 = [CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.00f]];
   overlay1 = [overlay1 imageByCroppingToRect:image.extent];
   overlay1 = [overlay1 imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent" withInputParameters:@{@"inputExtent":[CIVector vectorWithCGRect:image.extent],@"inputTopLeft":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(topLeft.x - 5, topLeft.y + 5)],@"inputBottomRight":[CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(bottomRight.x + 5, bottomRight.y)] }];
   image = [overlay1 imageByCompositingOverImage:image];
```

Where image is my primary layer & overlay1 is the secondary. Currently, secondary layer is a rectangular highlighter filled with red color

The four positions keeps on changing and I will be redrawing this overlay every time.

**I want to make it just the borders instead of the filled overlay**

I request for solution using the same process followed, since I'm completely new to iOS and will not be able to handle more changes for this.

Always thankful to stackoverflow helpers.